# Find $E(Y|X) $ for $f(x,y)=e^{-y}$, where $0 \leq x \leq y$

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, conditional-expectation

Find $E(Y|X) $ for $f(x,y)=e^{-y}$, where $0 \leq x \leq y$:

I know that $E(Y|X)=\int_{0}^x tf(y|x)dt = \int_{0}^x \frac{tf(x,y)dt}{f(x)}=\int_{0}^x \frac{te^{-y}dt}{\int_{x}^\infty e^{-y}dy}$.

However, I know that the answer should be $E(Y|X)=x+1$, and my work above does not give me this answer.
I think my problem comes from my bounds of integration for $f(x)$. I also tried $0$ and $\infty$ but that did not give me $x+1$ as well. 
Did I do something wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The support of the joint distribution is given as $0 \leq x \leq y$. Therefore, as what you have did in computing $f_X$, you should be integrating from $x$ to $+\infty$. Also from the definition of expectation, if you are integrating with respect to the dummy variable $t$, then the integrand should be $tf_{Y|X}(t|x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take care here (it's okay to use any dummy variable you want in integrating, but you have to make sure to plug it in for all instances). Also we have $y\ge x$ as the support for $y$ so all the integrals go from $x$ to $\infty:$ $$ E(Y|X=x) = \int_x^\infty yf(y\mid x) \;dy = \int_x^\infty y \frac{f(y,x)}{f(x)}\; dy = \frac{1}{\int_x^\infty e^{-y}dy}\int_x^\infty ye^{-y}dy$$